# How do I combine two data streams, filter them based on an objects field, and then merge them in RxJS?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am getting a little overwhelmed with combining data streams using declarative RxJS and I haven't been able to figure this one out.

I have two data streams like so:

```
seriesCards$ = this.http.get<SeriesCard[]>(this.seriesCardsUrl)
    .pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(CardsService.handleError)
    );
```

and,

```
allWatchCards$ = this.http.get<AllWatchCards[]>(this.watchCardsUrl)
    .pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(CardsService.handleError)
    );
```

As you can see, each one returns a different object array. I have a requirement in my app that now I need to combine them to return them all together based on a certain criteria for each one.

Each object has a field called `category` and that's the one I want to filter on for both.

Ideally I want my `service` to combine both the data streams and then my page/component to do the filtering and return each object from both object arrays based on that filter.

My `service.ts`:

```
watchCardWithSeriesCardsForDevotionals$ = combineLatest([
    this.allWatchCards$,
    this.seriesCards$
  ]).pipe(
    mergeMap(([watchCards, seriesCards]) =>
      merge(watchCards, seriesCards),
    ));
```

My `component.ts`

```
displayBothCards$ = this.cardService.watchCardWithSeriesCardsForDevotionals$
    .pipe(
      map(bothCards => bothCards) <!-- This is where I want to filter but it defaults to only the one objects field? -->
    );
```

For a reason I am not sure of, the `map(bothCards => bothCards)` is flattened to an object instead of an array of those objects so.

An example from a single data stream that I have that I am trying to do with two data streams:

```
displaySomething$ = this.cardService.allWatchCards$
    .pipe(
      map(somethingCards => somethingCards.filter(somethingCard => somethingCard.category === 'something')
        .sort(sortByDate))
    );
```

Any help and guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin`:

**Service**

```js
watchCardWithSeriesCardsForDevotionals$ = forkJoin({
  watchCards: this.allWatchCards$,
  seriesCards: this.seriesCards$
});
```

**Component**

```js
displayBothCards$ = this.cardService.watchCardWithSeriesCardsForDevotionals$
 .pipe(
   tap(({ watchCards, seriesCards }) => {
     console.log(watchCards);
     console.log(seriesCards);
   }),
   map(({ watchCards, seriesCards }) => {
     const filteredWatchCards = watchCards.filter((watchCard) => watchCard.category === 'devotional');
     const filteredSeriesCards = seriesCards.filter((seriesCard) => seriesCard.category === 'devotional');
      
    return { 
      myFilterWatchCards: filteredWatchCards as SeriesCards[]
      myFilterSeriesCards: filteredSeriesCards as AllWatchCards[]
    };
   })
 );
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="displayBothCards$ | async as bothCards">
 <div *ngFor="let watch of bothCards.myFilterWatchCards">
   <!-- watch.something -->
  </div>

 <div *ngFor="let serie of bothCards.myFilterSeriesCards">
   <!-- serie.something -->
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin#examples)

Comment: So here is what I have: 

```displayBothCards$ = this.cardService.watchCardWithSeriesCardsForDevotionals$
    .pipe(tap(({watchCards, seriesCards}) => {
        console.log(watchCards);
        console.log(seriesCards);
        }),
      map(({watchCards, seriesCards}) => { watchCards.filter(watchCard=>watchCard.category==='devotional');seriesCards.filter(seriesCard =>seriesCard.category=== 'devotional');}));```
but it's return type is of type Observable<void>? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Donnygroezinger, you are missing the `return` from your `map` You need to return something

Comment: Okay.. Well I use it in my HTML as an async. My other single data stream that I had an example of in my question didn't return anything, just maps it and then I use it in my html like so: `*ngIf="displayBothCards$ | async as bothCards"`

Comment: It almost works, but in the HTML, watch is of type ```any``` and so is series, and so looping through it, I'm not able to actually access its properties.

Comment: @Donnygroezinger set the data types within the `map` so you can have an object of type { myFilterWatchCards: SeriesCards[],  myFilterSeriesCards: AllWatchCards[]}. Is not that hard...

Comment: While I appreciate you helping me, what might not seem hard for you, can be hard for some; especially while learning. So thank you for your help.